# How to Button.PerformClick on a non active TabPage?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, button, tabcontrol

I'm working on a project that has TabControl with 5 TabPage controls, each TabPage has at least 10 buttons launching different forms.

On my Form's `Load` event, I loop through all the TabPages and store all the buttons in a collection (Name as Value, Text as Key) and also store all the buttons' Text in a ComboBox so that when I select this button's Text in the ComboBox and click the 'go' button, any button with the selected item as it Text will be clicked using this code...

```vb
Dim btnText As String = myCollection(myCombo.Text) 
Dim btnName as Button = DirectCast(Controls.Find(btnText, True)(0), Button) 
btnName.PerformClick()
```

The code only works with buttons whose TabPage is the selected one. How can I perform this click action on buttons without selecting their TabPage?

My objective is to allow the user to quickly perform a button click without looking for it on the TabPages.

Comment: **Hint-1:** The `Controls.Find(..)` method searches the controls keys/names and not their texts. **Hint-2:** `Controls.Find(btnText, True)(0)` returns the first match in the collection only, just like: `DirectCast(Controls.Find(btnText, True).First`.

Comment: The btnName.PerformClick() method will trigger the Click event only if the btnName is Visible and Enabled. If button is placed on an inactive TabPage, it is not Visible. Additionally the Validation of ActiveControl is triggered, when you call the PerfromClick(). If validation is canceled, then the Click event is not executed. Use Performclick() when you really need to simulate the click on the button. Otherwise extract the code from Click event in a separate method, and call the extracted method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `PerformClick`, take the code out of the `Click` event handler and put it in its own method. You can then call that method from wherever you like, including the `Click` event handler(s) of the `Buttons`.

In fact, don't even involve the `Buttons` in this case. Use the text or index from the `ComboBox` to identify the action to perform and then have each `Button` provide the same text or number. That assumes that each `Button` does the same thing but with a different form identifier.

Comment: Please how do i take the code out of Click event handler and put in it own method and call the method?

Comment: Ok i understand the first paragraph, please demonstrate the second paragraph with code sample

Comment: Visual Studio can help you with extracting a method, from multiple lines of code. The method parameters are added automatically. Check this for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-method?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Proper design would be to separate the user interface elements from the actions that should be executed when the user interface element is activated.

So your button click event handler should not execute the action, it should call a method that does this action.

The reason for this separation is, because it enables you to execute this action by using other interface elements. A common example is a button that does the same thing as a menu item. In your case: the action is the same whether you press the button or select it from the combobox.

```
private void OnFileNew() {...}
private void OnFileOpen() {...}
private void OnFileSave() {...}

private void OnButtonFileNewClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.OnFileNew();
}

private void OnMenuItemFileNewClicked(object sender, EventArge e)
{
    this.OnFileNew();
}

Dictionary<string, Action> comboActions = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
{
    { this.ButtonFileNew.Name, OnFileNew },
    { this.ButtonFileOpen.Name, OnFileOpen },
    { this.ButtonFileSave.Name, OnFileSave },
    ...
}

// fill the name with the names of the comboActions:
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(comboActions.Keys);

private void OnComboItemSelected(object sender, ...)
{
    string selectedName = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue;
    Action selectedAction = comboActions[selectedName];
    // execute the selectedAction:
    selectedAction();
}
```

Another possibility is to add KeyValuePairs to the combobox1.Items. Display the Key, and when an item is selected fetch the Value. This way you don't need a separate dictionary. However, this has the same disadvantage that you can only do this by selecting items from a combobox. If you also want a ListBox with this functionality, a separate dictionary would be better.

Comment: Yes I'm using a Collection to store the buttons' Names as Value and their Texts as Key and each combobox item is a key in the collection. When i select a combobox item and click run button, it returns a button that has this key from the collection, cast the returned object to button using DirectCast and execute a PerformClick() on it. Here everything works well, the only challenge is... if a tabpage is inactive, the action won't  be executed

Comment: So to avoid creating different methods for each  button (about 50 bittons), i used a for loop to activate the tabpages till it gets to the one that contains the searching button, pause there and perform the click action. This  is my working solution for now.